# Saving a username and password combination

Tags: xcode, ios5, nsstring, save

I have an app which asks the user for a username and password which I want to be saved (so the user doesn't have to reenter his data on every launch).
Of course I need to acces the username and password on the next application start. Can you tell me how to do it?

One more thing: the username (and pw) is saved in the AppDelegate but I need it in a different class later..

Answer (score 0):

The proper place to keep a username/password is in the keychain. It's made easier with open source wrappers such as [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain).

The way *I suspect* you want to do it is with NSUserDefaults, which you can read about in the [Preferences and Settings User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i).

Either way you can get at the information quite easily from elsewhere in your application.

But you really should do it the first way.

Give it a try and come back and ask a more specific question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I more liked it to do it with a settings bundle. This Bundle has two textfields and a toggle switch.
How do get the data (form) there?

Comment: I got it now. But is there a possibility to open the settings app on the iphone? Like if you want to open safari your code is: openURL: ... i want to open the settings then..